# URL with quotes causing errors

Tags: php, mysql, url

I am a newbie trying to work a PHP script for a gallery using a database. I recently changed the script and database so that the gallery will run based on 'photo_caption. The gallery works but if the database contains quotes ( for example the title Nature's Garden And Colors ) the script just pulls the part before the quotes ( so here just the word Nature instead of the whole caption Nature's Garden And Colors) and thereby breaks the links. Now the link structure is like this `/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado%20Journies&pcaption=Nature'sGardenAndColors` but because of the problem it shows as `/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado%20Journies&pcaption=Nature`

Is there any workaround this problem? How can I get make the $_GET statement to pull the complete photo_caption including the quotes? Thanks for any help...

I now use this code to get the photocaption for the link

```
$pcaption = isset($_GET['pcaption']) ? ($_GET['pcaption']) : 0;
```

if( $pcaption ) 
    {

```
    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT photo_caption, photo_description, photo_filename,photo_keywords FROM gallery_photos WHERE photo_caption='".addslashes($pcaption)."'" ); 

    list($photo_caption, $photo_description, $photo_filename, $photo_keywords) = mysql_fetch_array( $result ); 

    $nr = mysql_num_rows( $result ); 
     mysql_free_result( $result );     

    $p_caption = $photo_caption;
    $p_description = $photo_description;
    $p_keywords = $photo_keywords;

    //fill pid_array with sorted pids in current category 

    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT photo_caption FROM gallery_photos WHERE category_name='".addslashes($cname)."' ORDER BY photo_caption" ); 

    $ct = mysql_num_rows( $result );     

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

          $pid_array[] = $row[0]; 
    } 
    mysql_free_result( $result ); 

    if( empty($nr ) ) 
    { 
        print "%%%%NR is $nr";
        $result_final = "\t<tr><td>***No Photo found</td></tr>\n"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $result = mysql_query( "SELECT category_name FROM gallery_category WHERE category_name='".addslashes($cname)."'" ); 
        list($category_name) = mysql_fetch_array( $result ); 
        mysql_free_result( $result );     
        $result_final = "
        <div class=limagePage>
        <div class=llink><a href='viewgallery.php'>ALBUMS</a><span class=arrow>&gt;&gt</span><a href='viewgallery.php?cname=$cname>$category_name'</a></div>
         ";
        // display previous and next links if more than one photo 

        if ($ct > 1) 
        { 

            $key = array_search($pcaption , $pid_array); 
            $prev = $key - 1; 

            if ($prev < 0) $prev = $ct - 1; 
            $next = $key + 1; 

            if ($next == $ct) $next = 0; 

            //$cname = str_replace(" ","_",$cname);
            //$pcaption=str_replace(" ","_",$pcaption);

            $result_final .= "<div class='prevnext'>"; 
            $result_final .= "<span class='prev'><a href='viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".$pid_array[$next]."'><img src='photos/assets/left.png'  border='0' ></a></span>"; 
            $result_final .= "<span class='next'><a href='viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".$pid_array[$prev]."'><img src='photos/assets/right.png'  border='0' ></a></span>"; 
            $result_final .= "</div>";

        }            
    }
    //$cname = str_replace(" ","_",$cname);
    //$pcaption=str_replace(" ","_",$pcaption);
   $result_final .= "<div class=limage><table><tr><td><table class=image><tr>\n\t<td><a href='viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".$pid_array[$next]."'><img src='".$images_dir."/".$photo_filename."' border='0' alt='".$photo_keywords."' /></a>
  <div class=caption>".$photo_caption."</div> 
  <div class='excerpt'>".$photo_description."</div> 
  </td>                    
  </tr></table></td></tr></table><div class=underline></div></div>
  <!-- .limagePage --></div>    ";
```

Comment: I know it's untidy, but maybe just replace all `'` with `%27`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunatelly `urlencode` will not affect `'` try to `str_replace("'", "%27", $pid_array[$next])` maybe it helps. For example it works for Google in adress bar.

**UPD** `rawurldecode` (upd. correct: `rawurlencode` of course) can do it indeed, anyway the link will look a little bit ugly, full of %53, %27, etc. But don't forget to `urldecode($_GET['pcaption'])` before using it

Comment: vladkras..I think you are right. urlencode is not doing its trick. But str_replace is also not doing that.You are right about it working in Google's address bar though.

Comment: I don't understand, how can str_replace "not do this"? Then, try `rawurlencode` as I mentioned in my update (I've misstyped there, but I hope it's clear, that you have to use ENcode not DEcode). Your string will be _Nature%27s%20garden%20and%20colors_

Comment: Thank you vladkras ..I will try again and will keep you posted...:-)

Comment: Vladkras..you were right. Str_replace added in the right places did it. Thank you very much for that.

Comment: @yathrakaaran you're welocme!

Comment: Vladkras... I don't know if I should start this as a new topic but now there is a strange phenomenon, the code worked with str_replace () on wamp but not on live server..am I going crazy? Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: can you show an example on your server? did you just upload your file there?

Comment: Vladkras apparently my server was automatically escaping quotes(\') so I had to add one more line `$pcaption = str_replace("\\", "",$pcaption);` I don't know if this is correct in terms of the rules of the code but it works... if I am wrong please correct me...

Comment: are you sure you need two \\ here? your mysql DB server may escape qoutes with backslash on updating for security reason, so you can try [this](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stripslashes.php) or edit your `str_replace("\'", "%27", $pcaption)`

Comment: I will try stripslashes Vladkras.. thank you for answering my questions..you are awesome!.

Answer (score 3):

Try url encoding the values

```
urlencode($pid_array[$next])
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Musa..I tried this, but the problem still continues. I am not sure why :-(

Comment: @yathrakaaran did you do it for all the values in urls

Comment: Musa... urlencode is not doing its magic unfortunately. Yes I did try it all the values in urls. Thank you for your help.

Comment: urlencode doesn't change `'`, `"` and many more symbols, so this will not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the url before printing it in the link like so:

```
<a href='viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".urlencode($pid_array[$next])."'>
```

Otherwise think link will be cutoff early because the link will look like this:

```
<a href='viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=Nature's photo'>
                                                     ^ ends the link
```

Comment: I tried both of the answers here..but the problem continues. Here is a link where the site is uploaded. [link](http://www.rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado%20Journies) The first picture is what is giving me problem( the green image with trees, water)

Comment: Updated my answer with where the coding needs to happen. @iWantSimpleLife thanks, I misread the question and though we were pulling a link out of an array.

Comment: immulatin..I tried your updated answer also but unfortunately it is not working.. not sure why!

Answer (score 0):

use http_build_query(). With this function, you can convert a array to a http query, something like:

$data = array('name' => 'my name', 'city' => 'my city');

$url = "http://your_url.com/?" . http_build_query($data);

The output will be something like: http://your_url.com/?name=my%20name&city=my%20city

Answer (score 0):

```
rawurlencode($pid_array[$next])
```

should also do the trick.

note, using variable parsing quotes uses a bit more processing. since you're already doing it halfway..

```
$result_final .= "<span class='prev'><a href='viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".$pid_array[$next]."'><img src='photos/assets/left.png'  border='0' ></a></span>";
```

could be swapped for:

```
$result_final .= '<span class="prev"><a href="viewgallery.php?cname='.urlencode($cname).'&amp;pcaption='.urlencode($pid_array[$next]).'"><img src="photos/assets/left.png" border="0" ></a></span>';
```

also & isn't html valid, &amp;
now html valid, quotes dont matter and more efficient cpuwise.

Comment: Thank you for the tips about HTML. unfortunately rawurlencode is not working also...

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who tried to help me..I want to thank you all for your help. I figured out that besides quotes 'spaces' in the database where photo_caption is also causing issues. So I tried to trim the spaces in the code(it worked) and decided to avoid quotes for now. Just wanted to leave a follow up note... thanks everyone.

Comment: Finally got it working with Vladkras's idea! With str_replace it works. Thank you everyone..